# Add URL Parameter on 1 page in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, parameters, query-string

I have a Wordpress site and I want to add parameters to one of my page's URL.

https://example.com/recaptcha?keyword=hello (this is the URL I want to accomplish)

I've tried adding these codes to my theme's (Storevilla theme) function.php file but didn't work and received error saying there is an issue with <?php as it's not closed

```
<?php
function add_query_params_to_page_url( $url ) {
    if ( is_page( 'recaptcha' ) ) {
        $url = add_query_arg( array(
            'id' => 'keyword',
            'key' => 'hello',
        ), $url );
    }
    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'page_link', 'add_query_params_to_page_url' );
?>
```

Please help. I've been trying to do this for a couple of days now without any success.

Comment: What did you want to use the query parameter to the page for? As in you'd like to pick it up and use it, or when you visit the page example.com/recaptcha, it automatically appends ?keyword=hello to it. Also if your functions.php file shouldn't need a closing ?> tag, and should only ever need a single <?php at the start of the file. Does the error tell you what line the error is occuring on?

Comment: Yes, when I visit the page example.com/recaptcha, I want it to automatically appends ?keyword=hello to it. Yes, it's occuring in the line where the tag <?php located at. Exact error message was "syntax error, unexpected token "<", expecting end of file"

Comment: If you've got any other code in functions.php before that snippet, remove the <?php from this snippet and see how that goes. I think the snippet will also only filter urls that are linking to the page, rather than changing the url as people visit it (eg visiting example.com/recaptcha directly won't append the parameter)